# Unable to run waitress flask app on windows using command line

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, waitress

I am trying to run waitress WSGI on windows for a sample flask app but it is not working and getting an error

```
It had these arguments:
1. module 'myapp' has no attribute 'create_app'
```

I am using

```
waitress-serve --port=80 --call  "myapp:create_app"
```

The below are my 2 files in the same directory

myapp.py

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World!"

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.debug = True
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

create_app.py

```
from myapp import app

if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation for `waitress` says this

> `waitress-serve [OPTS] MODULE:OBJECT`

Your `MODULE:OBJECT` is given as `"myapp:create_app"` which means look for module `myapp` and find the name/object `create_app` in that.

Looking in the `myapp.py` , there is no `create_app` object/method in that. So you need to change the myapp.py like

```
from flask import Flask

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return "Hello World!"

    return app
```

Then it works!

Comment: Yes, thanks it worked, do you also know how to run the command waitress-serve --port=80 --call  "myapp:create_app" in background, so that if terminal gets closed it won't effect the process ? @Kris

Comment: You can accept my answer if it worked. Daemonizing a command in windows can be done using START /B <command>. I think there are enough answers on that.

Comment: Happy to Help!!